# I want to access and return a data of object by getting the data name from user which is passed to a function

Tags: python

```py
def lst_atribute(attribute, record):
    return [x.attribute for x in record]
```

**record** is an list which contains objects.

I want to create a list containing the values of an attribute from all the objects.

The objects have many attributes, I want the user to be able to specify the attribute name he wants the values for in the function parameter **attribute**

But I get the following error

```
lst_atribute
     return [x.attribute for x in record]
AttributeError: 'Pregnancy' object has no attribute 'attribute'
```

How can I get the values for an attribute by storing the attributes name in a variable?